# How to remove 'public' from Laravel URL?

Tags: laravel

I have a default laravel 8 project. I can only access my files if i use '/public/' to acess the route,and i do NOT want that. i just want to go 'localhost/ProjectName/Route' and not 'localhost/ProjectName/public/Route'.

I have tried changing .htacess, sending it to root,renaming server.php to index.php and a million other solutions i have found on the web.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization MemberHeader
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Remove public URL from the path
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

this is my htacess

Comment: It would help if you show your routes in your question. One possibility is you have a route group defined, such as `Route::name('public.')->group(function () { ...`

Comment: Which web server are you using? You should set the document root to `localhost/ProjectName/public`.

Comment: Either setup VirtualHosts for your projects or use `php artisan serve` from your project's root folder

Comment: Reset your `.htaccess` to what it was originally. If you use WAMP for instance, then you can do this: http://codedecode.co.in/blog/wordpress/set-up-virtual-host-with-wamp/ The key being that when you set up your virtual host, you will need to select the path to the public folder. If you are struggling on a live server, then the same principle applies, just ensure that the web root is the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your webs server configuration has the public directory set as the root folder rather than the root folder of the Laravel project.

Comment: where can i check that?

Comment: That will vary based on your hosting setup and which web server you are using. How are you hosting the website?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `.htaccess` file with following code. Please note, you don’t need to rename server.php to index.php or anything to remove /public name. Just using following code in your `.htaccess` file and you are good to go.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Result:
`website.com/public/route` to `website.com/route`

If you are trying to run laravel project in sub-folder within the root directory, above code won't work. Instead, use following code in your `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
</IfModule>
```

Result: `website.com/sub-project/public/route` to `website.com/sub-project/route`